# Visual studio 2010 Setup and Deployment Projects?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-installer

For those of you who are testing VS 2010 (or stay up-to-date with the blogs).. are there new features for building MSI's in VS 2010?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Biggest one is UI customization support, IMHO

[What's New in Deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5h2db54x(VS.100).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

The customized UI support is for ClickOnce projects not MSI projects.  The only update to VDPROJ is to support .NET 4.0 detection logic.

VDRPOJ is a pile of fertilizer and I wouldn't reccomend anyone use it anyways.  It's barely on life support until VS can switch officially over to WiX.